# How to Run a Command Line python script in IDLE in windows Environment

Tags: python-3.x

How to run a script in IDLE in Windows which takes command line arguments:

```
import sys
print('The command line arguments are:')
for i in sys.argv:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like IDLE provides a way to do this through the GUI, but you could do something like:

mocking them in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` where you intercept the command line arguments.

```
try:
    __file__
except:
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], 'argument1', 'argument2', 'argument2']
```

You can also try,

```
idle.py -r scriptname.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```